# Finding who (what) killed my process

Tags: java, linux, process, signals, kill

When i run my java program from bash script, after some times i receive a message :

```
MyProgram.bash: line 30:  4388 Killed
```

i make a parameter of bash as maximum :

```
ulimit -Ss unlimited
ulimit -Sc unlimited
ulimit -Sn 4096
```

But when i make CTRL+C after excuting, i have this error :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal SIGINT to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated
```

I add this information, when i run the same program whith the same paramater in another machine, i don't have this exception !
I run my program with these arguments (I have 5Go in memory)

```
jvmargs="-d64 -Xms512m -Xmx3G -Xss1G"
```

My algorithm take a lot memory because i use serialization. So why i have killed message, and not an exception as `OutOfMemoryError` ? What can i do to resolve problem ? and why when i runit in another machine with the same parameter it's work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reread that error message:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal SIGINT to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated

If OpenJDK cannot *correctly* handle the interruption signal (because it is completely out of memory), it maybe resorts to killing *itself*.

Comment: But why when i run the same program with the same parameter in another machine, it's work ?

Comment: Perhaps there's a difference between the two VMs?

Comment: Do they have the same amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

If a Process gets killed because Out Of Memory, a Segfault or another reason that causes Linux to kill it, you will find the problem description with a stacktrace in dmesg and/or your /var/log/dmesg or /var/log/messages logfile. Try typing dmesg at linux console.

```
# dmesg
[4374940.147496] php-fpm[15522]: segfault at 10000004d8 ip 00000010000004d8 sp 00007ffff9d41428 error 14 in libnss_dns.so.2[7ffe4d5a1000+5000]
[4375020.428429] soffice.bin[23336]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f8d63c566c0 sp 00007ffff529cc88 error 4 in libsvllo.so[7f8d63bb1000+108000]
```

Comment: There is nothing on dmesg or message or secure file but my java application was killed by OS. what could be the reason of that? 
PS: My server is running on Centos OS